# Adding tilde to electric pairs in org mode

Tags: org-mode, syntax-table, electric-pair-mode

I am trying to add the verbatim character `~` (tilde) as an electric-pair character in `org-mode`. Here is my attempt:

```
(with-eval-after-load 'org
 (modify-syntax-entry ?/ "(/" org-mode-syntax-table)
 (modify-syntax-entry ?= "(=" org-mode-syntax-table)
 (modify-syntax-entry ?~ "(~" org-mode-syntax-table))
```

This works for the `/` and `=` characters, but not for `~`. What do I need to do to add `~`?

Answer (score 5):

The syntax of `~` is changed by `org-mode` itself: as part of the definition of the mode, the file `org.el` contains

```
(modify-syntax-entry ?~ "_")
```

inside `(define-derived-mode org-mode...)`.
Since the command `org-mode` is not necessarily run at the time the file is loaded, you need to put your modification in to `org-mode-hook` instead, e.g.

```
(add-hook 'org-mode-hook (lambda ()  (modify-syntax-entry ?~ "$~" org-mode-syntax-table)))
```

so this run after the built-in syntax entry.  Your other definitions work, because `org` does not set the syntax for the those characters.

Note, as `~` is meant to match with itself, you should use the syntax class `$` rather than `(`.  The syntax class `(` indicates that the given character is paired with a *different* symbol.